# find out the number of grids possible in a square logic is write but the code not accepts more than six inputs ,it stops and says .exe stopped working

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

What is the wrong here?  Can't we increase the array size like this:

```
int main() {
    int k = 0, c;
    int b[k];
    cin >> c;
    do {
        b[k++] = c;
        cin >> c;
    } while (c != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int k=0,c; int b[k]` defines an array `b` of size `0`. So you won't be able to address this array, e.g. by `b[1]=10`, as this exceeds array bounds and yields undefined behaviour.

As it is C++, use a `std::vector` instead of the "c-style" dynamic arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int c;
    std::vector<int> b;
    cin >> c;
    do {
        b.push_back(c);
        cin >> c;
    } while (c != 0);

    for (auto c  : b) {
        cout  << c << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: but i'm increasing the size of array b[k++] every time till user presses zero

Comment: undefined behaviour; it could "work" until 10.000, but also not even for 0; The compiler could even  ignore the complete thing, crash, cry, ...

Comment: so do i have to allocate the memory dynamically?

Comment: And  with `b[k++]` you do not increase the array size; you just access an element of it. The array is defined  outside the loop with `int b[k]`

Comment: @SrjSunny Use `std::vector` if you want an array that can grow.

Comment: @StephanLechner , will you please explain that how come b[k++] is not expanding its size  but if suppose i give int b[10], and use b[k++] to enter some elements it works why ?

Comment: @StephanLechner thank you very much I get it now, I think its the compiler which created problem,  on Codeblocks it accepted till 6 inputs but on ideone it was not working.

Comment: @SrjSunny The behavior is undefined.  It may "work" on one system/compiler and "fail" on another.  In this case, it probably doesn't crash until you run off the end of the memory page that contains `b`, which may be different sizes on different systems or laid out differently by different compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
vector<int> b{istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator()}
```

This will read from the `cin` and populate a `vector<int>`.
Note that you'll have to send an EOF to terminate the loop. On my computer that's a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: why EOF file.?I want to terminate it when entered 0.

Comment: Because `istream_iterators` terminate on EOF. Which in your specific case is a good thing because it allows your code to accept a 0.